# Not able to get data that is in Bengali language from server using jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am not able to get data that is in Bengali language from server using ajax. The data from server is getting replaced by something I don't know. But if I normally set the data means not using ajax, data is getting displayed properly. My code is:

```
<meta content="html/text" charset="UTF-8"> in .jsp file

$.ajax({
   url: "",
   data: "a=a",
   contentType: "charset=utf-8",
   method: "get",
   success:function(){
   },
   failure:function(){
   }
});
```

I have taken reference from [UTF8 encoding not working when using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877852/utf8-encoding-not-working-when-using-ajax), but even this did not work.

Answer (score 2):

The error is in the [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) statement config.

`contentType="charset=utf-8",`

Here, you should use `:` instead of `=`.

See the error highlighted in the code below.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "YOUR URL HERE?myparam1=value1&param2=value2",
    data: "a=a",
    contentType: "charset=utf-8",
    //         ^
    method: "GET",
    success: function(resp) {},
    failure: function(err) {}
});
```

Comment: also put parameter in success handler, so you can get response in that.

Comment: yea,i have tried this also. the response i get from this parameter is again
????? instead of banguali content.....

Comment: @PriyankaGupta Can you create `jsfiddle` demo